# Integer returning function is called without assigning the returning value to anything

Tags: java

```
class Example(){
    public void disp(float num1, int num2){
        System.out.println("First disp method in Example class");
        System.out.println("num1="+num1);
    }

    public int disp(int num1, int num2){
        System.out.prinln("Second disp method in Example class");
        System.out.println("num2="+num2);
        return num1;
    }
    class Demo(){
        public static void main(String args[]){
        Example obj=new Example();
        obj.disp(60,20);
    }
}
```

output:
Second disp method in example class
`num1=60`

How is this possible?  The second display method returns an integer type value and the calling syntax does not stores that value anywhere.

And the second question is that no matter if I save this program as `Example.java` or `Demo.java`, it runs fine. But as far as my knowledge is concerned, the file name should be same as that of the class accommodating the main function.

Comment: just because a method returns something, doesn't mean the method calling that needs to do anything with the value

Comment: There are lots of tutorial out there on function overloading or overriding. Search on Google!

Answer (score 2):

Running your provided program I get the output

```
Second disp method in Example class
num2=20
```

This is because the method signature with two `int` parameters is an exact match to your provided method invocation.
Regarding the return type, Java doesn't even consider the return type when deciding which method to use. It is illegal to have two methods differing only by return type. You can read more in [the language specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).

The fact that you don't store the returned `int` anywhere is irrelevant, Java doesn't demand that you do.

**EDIT**
Regarding your second question, the only rule is that you can only have one `public` class in each file, and the name of that class has to match the filename.
Since your `Example` class isn't `public` though, that rule doesn't apply. You can have any number of non-public classes in a file.

Comment: keppil, could you help me with the second question?

Comment: @rakeshkumar: Added answer to your second question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to make sure you have recompiled your code, not just save it. The listing above would definitely output:

```
Second disp method in example class num2=20
```

Comment: i apologize. i got the answer of first question by keppil. could you help me with my second query?

Answer (score 0):

the file name should be same as that of the class accommodating the main function.
this is not correct. if your class A is public than file Name will be A.java.
 and in inner class if you want to create main method than that class should be static

Comment: but in the above program, neither of the classes is public. so what should be the appropriate file name? and will it run fine if i save the file with the name Demo.java or Example.java?

Comment: Example.java because that is the main class and Demo.java is inner class.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your second question, as you do not declare either class as public, it doesn't matter what name you give to the file. The minute you declare one of the classes as public, the filename must match it. Attempting to declare more than one public class in the same file is a compiler error.

For maintainability, try to keep to one class per file where possible.